# How to get the execution plan using LINQ to SQL/ADO.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq-to-sql, sql-execution-plan

Is it possible to get the execution plan of a LINQ to SQL or ADO.NET Query programatically for displaying in debug information?  If so, how?

Comment: I don't know about LINQ specifically but here is a solution for programatically obtaining query plan.  To do the same for LINQ it seems you'd have to modify the generated files heavily.  Should be doable, complex, but doable.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/aaf5e9c9-a222-414a-baed-5c0adcc329e2

Comment: Did you accomplish this?  I'd kind of like to see the solution if you can re post at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there are 2 things you will need.

A custom implementation of `DbConnection`, `DbCommand` and `DbDataReader`. You can use that to intercept all the SQL sent to the DB. You basically set it up so you have a layer that logs all the SQL that is run. (we plan to open source something in this area in the next few months, so stay tuned)

A way to display an make sense of the data, which happens to be open source here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/345/how-unsung-am-i (see the include execution plan option)

---

Another approach is to do the diagnostics after the fact by looking at the proc cache. [sys.dm_exec_query_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx) contains cached plan handles which you can expand.

Comment: Have a link for the open sourced exec plan display?

Comment: This might be the needed wrapper: https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/HowTo/ProfileSql